why cannot make inline custom getter()?
In Kotlin, when you define an inline getter, you encounter the "Inline property cannot have backing field" error. Why does defining an inline getter make the compiler recognize it as an inline property?
class Test(
    val firstName: String
) {

    val test
        inline get() = "$firstName"

}

kotlin defines property that has getter, setter function. so if i define inline getter, compiler try to make property?

I'm not exactly sure what's your question. val is how we define properties - no matter inline or not. I suppose the problem is that inline getter with a backing field would require external classes to access the field directly and the field is private, so this is not possible.

@broot I think that is probably the reason.

Maybe the question is: why it creates a backing field in the above example? I believe it doesn't. The above example compiles just fine for me: https://pl.kotl.in/js7p6U6Be

See decompiled code:
public final class Test public constructor(firstName: kotlin.String) {
public final val firstName: kotlin.String /* compiled code */

public final val test: kotlin.String /* compiled code */
    public final get 
}

JVM also creates property.
